# How to get more than 50 files from SD card folder?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Few days ago I was surprised that the method I'm using ([ExternalStorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.storage.externalstoragefolder.getfilesasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) returns list of maximum 50 files as a result. I haven't found any info about this limitation, only method description:

> Gets the top-level files in the current folder.

I've tried to find more information, but access to [External Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ExternalstorageSDcard) is very limited and I see no option to find the next files.

Normally I use the method like this:

```
var files = await currentFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

I've registered App for a file association, I can see 50 files as a result, but I cannot access the next ones.

Is there any method to list more than 50 files?

Comment: "the top-level files" means files that are directly in the given ExtenralStorageFolder not in any of its subfolders.

Comment: @lisp You are probably right - I would also understand it this way.